# Most efficient way to create date formatter for May 23 '17, 12:30

Tags: ios, swift

What format i should use for getting the date with '. like May 23 '17, 12:30. Tried MMM dd ' yy hh:mm a so im getting Mar 23, yy hh:mm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with most efficient here but to get the result you want use

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd ''yy, hh:mm a"
```

Comment: This date format is wrong. Why would you use `hh` (01-12) 12hours format without AM/PM symbol? It should be `H` (0-23) or `HH` (00-23) 24hours or just add the am/pm info to it

Comment: @LeoDabus, yes I lost the a.